Sorting on a Customized DataGrid WPF
Data cant be sorted when header of a column is pressed
In a default datagrid, items can be sorted if the header is simply pressed, however, in this case, since I used a customized datagrid, sorting the items doesnt seem to work
<Application x:Class="CoinControl.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CoinControl"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero2"
             xmlns:Icon="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks">

    <Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="gridEditButton"
               TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="#512da8"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="#4a148c"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
                    Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                    Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                CornerRadius="5"
                                Padding="5"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                         Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="#673ab7"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="gridRemoveButton"
               TargetType="Button"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource gridEditButton}">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="#d32f2f"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                        Value="#b71c1c"/>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                 Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="#f44336"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="gridButtonIcon"
               TargetType="Icon:PackIconMaterial">
            <Setter Property="Width"
                    Value="12"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" 
                    Value="12"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                    Value="Center"/>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="DataGridRowStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="Background" 
                    Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 4 0 0"/>
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Margin="2,0,0,0" Text="!" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                        <Border x:Name="DGR_Border" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                BorderThickness="0" 
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                                CornerRadius="5"
                                Padding="0 8">
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                                <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"/>
                                <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#623ed0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffff"/>
                </Trigger>

                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#623ed0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffff"/>
                </Trigger>

                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#dfdfdf"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderGripperStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="8"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeWE"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#69717d"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15 0 15 10"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Grid>
                            <theme:DataGridHeaderBorder Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                                        IsPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" 
                                                        IsHovered="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" 
                                                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                                        SortDirection="Ascending" 
                                                        SeparatorVisibility="{TemplateBinding SeparatorVisibility}" 
                                                        SeparatorBrush="{TemplateBinding SeparatorBrush}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </theme:DataGridHeaderBorder>
                            <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
                            <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static DataGrid.FocusBorderBrushKey}" Color="#FF000000"/>
        <Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15 0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                BorderThickness="0" 
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="Border" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
                            <Polygon x:Name="Arrow" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="8,8,3,3" Opacity="0.15" Points="0,10 10,10 10,0" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Arrow" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="DataGridStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
            <Setter Property="Background" 
                    Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" 
                    Value="#222528"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="VisibleWhenSelected"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="Column"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 10 0 0"/>
            <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single"/>
            <Setter Property="SelectionUnit" Value="FullRow"/>
            <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="CanUserResizeRows" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="8.5"/>
            <Setter Property="CanUserSortColumns" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="ColumnWidth" Value="*"/>
            <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="None"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/fonts/#Montserrat"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="false">
                                <ScrollViewer.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Button Command="{x:Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}" Focusable="false" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Width="{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                            <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                            <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                            <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Column="2" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                                            <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Orientation="Horizontal" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </ScrollViewer.Template>
                                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>


I tried setting CanUserSortColumns = "True", it didnt work
Another test is setting the object's CanUserSortColumns but it also didnt work

You have overridden and defined a lot of styles but never applied them. I suggest to rework your styles from scratch.
